Largest Contentful Paint element 5,400 ms on mobile but I dont know what to do
I am developing a website for a client, but I am not an expert in web development (I am more of a front end person).
My site is loading slowly on mobile https://pagespeed.web.dev/analysis/https-www-yorzint-com/ng8jumfmon?form_factor=mobile
Analsysi from Google says that on mobile the Largest Contentful Paint element 5,400 ms is from this element

AWAKEN YOUR SENSES WITH OUR BREWS
h3 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default"

Google Page Analyzer Screenshot
H3 Location
But this is just a h3 class, and google doesnt even provide a recommendation on what to do to fix this. Should I just remove this?
Thank you
I havent tried anything as I thought that h3 class element is important
